# tomcat config causes 2 copies of @Service to run

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a `ScheduledExecutor` that runs on `@PostConstruct` of some of my `@Service`. however, this tomcat config causes 2 copies of `@Service` to run and removing either one would cause the `@Controller` in the wars to not work.

how to resolve this? i need the `@Service` to be singleton so that there is only  one `Executor` that runs some code.

setting the `Executor` to `static` would make it one `Executor` only, but is there a way to achieve this at the config level?

*web.xml*

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

*servlet-context.xml*

```xml
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<bean id="properties" class="my.package.common.properties.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>WEB-INF/classes/system.properties</value>
      <value>WEB-INF/classes/db.properties</value>
      <value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />
```

Comment: How do you know it’s related to tomcat config ? Could you perhaps add code for your service ? Also if possible reproducible GitHub repo would be good. Thanks.

Comment: I print stuff out in the Service. when i comment away either applicationContext.xml away, there would be 1 bean left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very likely related with the following import in your `servlet-context.xml`:

```xml
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```

Probably in your `web.xml` file you are including the following web application context listener:

```xml
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In a typical Spring MVC application, this listener is responsible for initializing the Spring **root application context** based on the information provided in the XML files indicated in the web application context param `contextConfigLocation`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

On the other hand, you are initiating a second **child application context** when configuring the Spring `DispatcherServlet`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

In your example, this second context is based on the configuration provided in `servlet-context.xml`.

It is very important to understand that **both contexts are related** in such a way that all the beans defined in the root application context are accessible to the child context associated with the `DispatcherServlet` (the contrary is not true).

This allows you to organize and provide the right hierarchy for your beans: for example, the root application context usually defines services and common components and configuration (database, security, async support, cache, etcetera) whereas the child context defines beans related to MVC stuff.

This context hierarchy is very well explained in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy):

[image: mvc spring contexts hierarchy]

As you told, when you include the following `import` in your `servlet-context.xml` file:

```xml
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```

you are in fact duplicating all the stuff defined in the root context.

To solve the problem, please, remove that line from `servlet-context.xml`.

According to your comments after doing that all your controllers report an error `404`. Probably the cause is that after removing `applicationContext.xml` Spring is unable to find any `Controller`s: please, be sure that you include `component-scan` in `servlet-context.xml` as well, pointing to the packages where your controllers are defined. In `servlet-context.xml` include:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.controllers" />`
```

Include in this way in `servlet-context.xml` any other MVC resource you need (view resolvers, etcetera) as well.

Ideally, in `applicationContext.xml` only is necessary to scan for components like services, repositories, and similar stuff.

Comment: after removing the `<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />` config from servlet-context.xml, all endpoints return 404.

Comment: Hi @theAnonymous, thank you very much for the feedback. Probably it is because any beans dependencies. Does the application provide some errors in the logs?

Comment: @theAnonymous The problem you reported may be related to the fact that Spring is unable to find your controllers when you remove `<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />` from `servlet-context.xml,`: please, be sure that you include `component-scan` to point to the packages where your controllers are defined in `servlet-context.xml`: `<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.controllers" />`. I updated the answer as well. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have initialized application context twice.
First of all `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` servlet creates its own internal web application context, you can check it in java docs

```java
/**
 * Create a new {@code DispatcherServlet} that will create its own internal web
 * application context based on defaults and values provided through servlet
 * init-params. Typically used in Servlet 2.5 or earlier environments, where the only
 * option for servlet registration is through {@code web.xml} which requires the use
 * of a no-arg constructor.
 * ...
 */
public DispatcherServlet() {
     super();
     setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
}
```

And the second initialization is processing by following config:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I think you have `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml` like on example above.

As solution you can remove context params for `DispatcherServlet`.